# Read only after certain characters textbox in c# of Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm reading text files one line at a time using C# in Unity3d, but everything works fine, but I want to read them after the second =. The format of the data in the txt file is as follows:

252|0.5|3|82|583

=

3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|1

=

5|3|0|
2|3|0|
2|3.5|0|
2|4|0|
4|4.5|0|
2|4.5|0|
2|5|0|
2|5.5|0|
5|5.833|0|
5|6|0|
2|6|0|
2|6.5|0|
2|7|0|
2|7.5|0|
4|7.5|0|
2|8|0|
2|8.5|0|
5|9|0|
2|9|0|
2|9.5|0|
2|10|0|
4|10.5|0|
2|10.5|0|
2|11|0|
2|11.5|0|
5|11.833|0|
5|12|0|
2|12|0|
2|12.5|0|
2|13|0|
4|13.5|0|
2|13.5|0|
7|14|0|
8|14.5|0|
5|15|0|
2|15|0|
2|15.5|0|
2|16|0|
4|16.5|0|
2|16.5|0|
2|17|0|
2|17.5|0|
5|17.833|0|
5|18|0|
2|18|0|
2|18.5|0|
2|19|0|
4|19.5|0|
2|19.5|0|
2|20|0|
2|20.5|0|
2|21|0|
5|21|0|
2|21.5|0|
2|22|0|
4|22.5|0|
2|22.5|0|
2|23|0|
2|23.5|0|
5|23.833|0|
5|24|0|
2|24|0|

Comment: Sounds great.  Let us know how you go.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to compare strings? If so:

1. Read each line until one of them is `=`. Don’t do anything with these lines unless you want to.
2. Read each line until one of them is `=` again. Don’t do anything with these lines unless you want to.
3. You are now reading the lines after the second `=`.